# Why is Cassandra crashing whenever I try to run DataStax Kafka Connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, apache-kafka-connect

***Goal***: My goal is to use Kafka to send messages to a Cassandra sink using Kafka Connect.

I've deployed Kafka and Cassandra and I am able to work with each of them individually - I have no problem sending data to Kafka, using producers to pass messages, and using consumers to consume them. I have no problem using cqlsh to create tables and insert data into them. However, *whenever I try to deploy the DataStax Apache Kafka Connector, Cassandra seems to crash.*

I am trying to learn how to use Kafka Connect using just one Kafka producer, broker, and one Cassandra keyspace using the standalone mode. I've configured both ***connect-standalone.properties*** and the ***cassandra-sink-standalone.properties*** following the instructions shown on DataStax: https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/kafka/kafkaStringJson.html

**connect-standalone.properties**

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

plugin.path= *install_location*/kafka-connect-cassandra-sink-1.4.0.jar
```

**cassandra-sink-standalone.properties**

```
name=stocks-sink
connector.class=com.datastax.kafkaconnector.DseSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=stocks_topic
topic.stocks_topic.stocks_keyspace.stocks_table.mapping = symbol=value.symbol, ts=value.ts, exchange=value.exchange, industry=value.industry, name=key, value=value.value
```

Then, the Kafka Connector is started using `bin/connect-standalone.sh connect-standalone.properties cassandra-sink-standalone.properties`.

About 95% of the time I attempt to launch Kafka Connector, Cassandra crashes. Running `bin/nodetool status` shows the message:

> nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'

In the *system.log* and *debug.log* logs, there is no indication that Cassandra has even crashed. The last line just remains as:

> INFO  [main] 2023-01-31 00:00:00,143 StorageService.java:2806 - Node localhost/127.0.0.1:7000 state jump to NORMAL

And in the Kafka Connect logs, the error messages states:

```
[2023-01-31 15:24:47,803] INFO [plc-sink|task-0] DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.6.0 (com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.DefaultMavenCoordinates:37)
[2023-01-31 15:24:47,947] INFO [plc-sink|task-0] Could not register Graph extensions; this is normal if Tinkerpop was explicitly excluded from classpath (com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.context.InternalDriverContext:540)
[2023-01-31 15:24:47,948] INFO [plc-sink|task-0] Could not register Reactive extensions; this is normal if Reactive Streams was explicitly excluded from classpath (com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.context.InternalDriverContext:559)
[2023-01-31 15:24:47,997] INFO [plc-sink|task-0] Using native clock for microsecond precision (com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.time.Clock:40)
[2023-01-31 15:24:47,999] INFO [plc-sink|task-0] [s0] No contact points provided, defaulting to /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.metadata.MetadataManager:134)
[2023-01-31 15:24:48,190] WARN [plc-sink|task-0] [s0] Error connecting to Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=3247c5e4), trying next node (ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)) (com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.control.ControlConnection:34)
[2023-01-31 15:24:48,200] ERROR [plc-sink|task-0] WorkerSinkTask{id=plc-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:196)
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=3247c5e4): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException.copy(AllNodesFailedException.java:141)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.build(SessionBuilder.java:612)
    at com.datastax.oss.kafka.sink.state.LifeCycleManager.buildCqlSession(LifeCycleManager.java:518)
    at com.datastax.oss.kafka.sink.state.LifeCycleManager.lambda$startTask$0(LifeCycleManager.java:113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
    at com.datastax.oss.kafka.sink.state.LifeCycleManager.startTask(LifeCycleManager.java:109)
    at com.datastax.oss.kafka.sink.CassandraSinkTask.start(CassandraSinkTask.java:83)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:312)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:187)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:244)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
    Suppressed: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler$InitRequest.fail(ProtocolInitHandler.java:342)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ChannelHandlerRequest.writeListener(ChannelHandlerRequest.java:87)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:551)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:183)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ChannelHandlerRequest.send(ChannelHandlerRequest.java:76)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler$InitRequest.send(ProtocolInitHandler.java:183)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler.onRealConnect(ProtocolInitHandler.java:118)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ConnectInitHandler.lambda$connect$0(ConnectInitHandler.java:57)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:570)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:549)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:608)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:321)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:337)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        ... 1 more
        Suppressed: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:9042
        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:716)
            at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
            at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
    Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.newClosedChannelException(AbstractChannel.java:957)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:921)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:354)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:897)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1372)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:748)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:740)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:726)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:127)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:748)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:763)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:788)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:756)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:806)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1025)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:294)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ChannelHandlerRequest.send(ChannelHandlerRequest.java:75)
        ... 20 more
```

In the 5% of the time that Cassandra doesn't actually crash, the following message shows up in Kafka Connect's logs:

```
[2023-01-31 15:41:32,839] INFO [plc-sink|task-0] DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.6.0 (com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.DefaultMavenCoordinates:37)
[2023-01-31 15:41:32,981] INFO [plc-sink|task-0] Could not register Graph extensions; this is normal if Tinkerpop was explicitly excluded from classpath (com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.context.InternalDriverContext:540)
[2023-01-31 15:41:32,982] INFO [plc-sink|task-0] Could not register Reactive extensions; this is normal if Reactive Streams was explicitly excluded from classpath (com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.context.InternalDriverContext:559)
[2023-01-31 15:41:33,037] INFO [plc-sink|task-0] Using native clock for microsecond precision (com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.time.Clock:40)
[2023-01-31 15:41:33,040] INFO [plc-sink|task-0] [s0] No contact points provided, defaulting to /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.metadata.MetadataManager:134)
[2023-01-31 15:41:33,254] INFO [plc-sink|task-0] [s0] Failed to connect with protocol DSE_V2, retrying with DSE_V1 (com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ChannelFactory:224)
[2023-01-31 15:41:33,263] INFO [plc-sink|task-0] [s0] Failed to connect with protocol DSE_V1, retrying with V4 (com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ChannelFactory:224)
[2023-01-31 15:41:34,091] INFO [plc-sink|task-0] WorkerSinkTask{id=plc-sink-0} Sink task finished initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:313)
[2023-01-31 15:41:34,092] INFO [plc-sink|task-0] WorkerSinkTask{id=plc-sink-0} Executing sink task (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:198)
...
```

Versions:

- Apache Cassandra 4.0.7
- Apache Kafka 3.3.1
- DataStax Apache Kafka Connector 1.4.0

I am currently using WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04.5 on Windows 11, with the following specs:

- CPU: 4 Cores
- Memory: 8GB RAM
- Disk (SSD): 250 GB

Seeing that it actually works 5% of the time, I suspect that it's an OOM problem as outlined in https://community.datastax.com/questions/6947/index.html (and I sometimes just happen to have enough memory?). I've tried the solution in this article but it didn't help. How can I configure Cassandra / Kafka Connect to avoid this problem? Is this just a matter of needing a computer with more memory?

Comment: Kafka Connect defaults to start with Xmx2g, so you can at least triple that (although WSL2 VM may have less memory) but no part of your error is saying OOM... Are both Kafka and Cassandra running in WSL2, or is it one running under Windows? Maybe you can show a [mcve] using Docker Compose so we can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track when you suggested that memory is an issue.

I have a "small" Windows Surface Pro I use to replicate issues like yours. I'm also running Ubuntu 20.04 with WSL2 on this laptop.

By default, Windows allocates half of system RAM to WSL2 so on my sub-8GB RAM installation, my Ubuntu installation takes up 3.7GB of memory. A vanilla installation of Cassandra (out-of-the-box zero configuration), starts with 1.3GB of memory allocated to it so there's only 2.4GB left for everything else.

What I suspect is happening is that when you start Kafka on the same node, Ubuntu runs out of memory and it triggers the Linux `oom-killer`. Although the end result is similar, the trigger is slightly different to [what I described in the post you linked](https://community.datastax.com/questions/6947/) so my recommendation to explicitly set `disk_access_mode` doesn't help in this situation.

As a workaround, configure Cassandra to only allocate 1GB of memory by setting the `MAX_HEAP_SIZE` in `conf/cassandra-env.sh`:

```
MAX_HEAP_SIZE="1G"
```

Kafka is configured with 1GB by default but if it isn't, set the following in `bin/kafka-server-start.sh`:

```
    export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx1G -Xms1G"
```

By setting both, there should be over 1GB left for Ubuntu and hopefully allow you to run your tests. Cheers!